# Возможно ли выполнить в Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic, office

В ячейках введены данные по умолчанию, каждая ячейка относится к определенному параметру. 
1. Кликаю по баттону
2. Ввожу какую ячейку необходимо изменить. (изменить возраст, изменить номер телефона и т. п.)
3. Кликаю ОК и все значения во ячейках перерасчитываются по необходимым зависимостям.

Каждая ячейка зависит от какой либо и считает свое значение в отношении других.

Comment: Да, вполне возможно.

Comment: 1. Как сформулировали вопрос, так Вам и ответили. 2. В целом - комплексная задача, а не конкретный вопрос.